# Cant reach nodejs from the browser

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have project that runs inside of docker locally, but after purging all the cache nodejs container refuses to work normally on docker-compose up, browser returns "the connection was reset", though according to docker ps container is online and deployed to 0.0.0.0:3000 as usual.

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
      args:
        USER_ID: 1000
        GROUP_ID: 1001
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST_BACK}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER_BACK}
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER_BACK}

  php:
    build:
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST_BACK}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER_BACK}
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER_BACK}
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    links:
      - mariadb

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: password
    volumes:
      - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: mariadb

  nodejs:
    build:
        dockerfile: nodejs.dockerfile
        args:
          APP_PATH_HOST_FRONT: ${APP_PATH_HOST_FRONT}
          APP_PATH_CONTAINER_FRONT: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER_FRONT}
    ports:
        - 3000:3000
        - 3001:3001
    restart: always
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER_FRONT}
```

Nodejs dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

#EXPOSE 3000

ARG APP_PATH_HOST_FRONT

ARG APP_PATH_CONTAINER_FRONT

WORKDIR ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER_FRONT}

COPY ${APP_PATH_HOST_FRONT}/package.json ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER_FRONT}

RUN npm install

COPY ${APP_PATH_HOST_FRONT} ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER_FRONT}

EXPOSE 3000:3000

CMD npm run dev
```

NGINX dockerfile:

```
server {
    listen  80;

    root /var/www/html/back/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

Though I can normally reach adminer on port 8080. I also tried to swap ports, but nodejs is unreachable from the browser no matter which port is(though adminer works fine on 3000 too). What could be an issue?

I'm running on Windows 10 home, WSL2.

Comment: I encounter this problem once, I was using another stack but I remember that you need to modify an nginx file named `nginx.conf` in order to receive your requests as a reverse proxy and send it to the backend service (REST API). At this point in the time I have not the code in a public repo. to show some snippets about it.

Comment: After observing your `.yaml` I have a question, why do you need a php service?, it is just a concern.

Comment: Ah, I thought locally I could use nodejs without NGINX and well, it worked without before. I've modified my original question with PHP dockerfile chunk, it serves as API and nodejs with nuxt/socket.io on front

Comment: I just noticed that nginx container faces same issue as nodejs one, works fine by docker ps, but unreachable by browser.

Comment: Check the following gist: https://gist.github.com/realFranco/82b268231a6d0332adcfb420f99afba6 in there I expose a solution that could solve your question. I have not to much time to execute your `compose.yml` and I am not very familiar with a "php" stack to introduce a correct "nginx" configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think it was some issue with docker/docker-compose caching. I've started docker-compose up with different name of  COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME and now i can reach nginx and other stuff works fine, only left to wire up nodejs in ngnix conf. Strange though, i used for several times command docker system prune -a, but seems it doesn't purge all the cache/data.